# How to create the button in android?

Tags: android, android-button

I am facing the problem in creating the button like given image

[image]

How to create the keyword title 1 and keyword title 2 button with the checkbox on the button.

Comment: Is it dynamically added or just static two buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Keyword Title 1" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i tried this method but the checkbox is viewing behind the button

Comment: @PrabhaKaran Sorry for late replay..Your problem resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below code
`res/layout/MainLayout.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/keyword_title_1"
            android:id="@+id/section_label"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/textview_background"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

`res/drawable/textview_background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <stroke android:color="@color/black" android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

`res/drawable/checkbox_selector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox" 
          android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkboxselected" 
          android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox"/>    
</selector>
```